# How to use a horizontal WrapPanel in Panorama (sketchflow)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend, sketchflow

I would like to use a horizontal WrapPanel in my application (like the People Hub). However, I have to start with a SketchFlow project.
My question is: how can I do?

In fact, I saw that I had to add the dll to my project but how do next? If I extend my panoramaitem, rendering is not pretty (the second item does not move).

[Screenshot http://upload.yamalandia.com/rep1/247871330688.PNG](http://upload.yamalandia.com/rep1/247871330688.PNG)

In this picture you can see how it looks: it's not nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you post the xaml?

Just to verify, you added a reference to the SL toolkit dll from the SL version (not the Windows Phone version, as you are actually creating a SL app in SketchFlow).

If that control in the screenshot is the wrap panel, you could set it to an explicit size to fix the problem most likely.

Comment: All right, I did what I wanted :) When copying / pasting XAML from my Visual Studio solution (and changing a few things)